# use union result rows in subselect

Tags: sql, merge, union

I got two tables:

```
Employers:

id_employe, id_department, city_empl

1, 2,    Barcelona
2, 2,    Barcelona
3, 1,    Madrid
4, null, Sevilla

Departaments: 

id_departament, city_dpt

1, Barcelona
2, Bilbao
3, Madrid
```

What I need first is to get all the distinct cities in both tables and for each city I have to list how many employers work there.

So, my query should return something similar to:

```
Barcelona, 2
Madrid,    1
Sevilla,   1
Bilbao,    0/null
```

I tried to get all the cities with a UNION and after do a select to the employers table for each one of the UNION result rows, but SQL doesn't allow that because of the multiple results returned by the UNION query.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT City, SUM(id_employe IS NOT NULL) AS Num FROM (
  SELECT city_empl AS City, id_employe
  FROM Employers
  UNION ALL
  SELECT city_dpt AS City, null AS id_employe
  FROM Departaments
) AS intbl
GROUP BY City
```

Comment: Exactly what I need, it have to be adapted to the real table but seems that will work, thanks !!

Comment: The naming of the view "AS intbl" is what fixed my query. Thanks!